# In MVC, Can View talk to View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

In my `MVC` architecture, I need a `UIView`(testView) to be a subview of `UIView`(mainView). These both views I am creating programmatically. So should I create testView from ViewController and assign to mainView or mainView will directly communicate with testView and add it as subview?

Comment: Hi see the answer i wrote i gave an example hope it will help you

Comment: View never talk to each other because they have do not know world is exist, so you have to be brief clear about what do you want to achieve so that we can understand pattern

Comment: it depends how complex the test view is . if test view is very simple then the approach in my opinion should be, created from the viewcontroller else you can write a class for test view. Create it's instance and add it to main view.

Comment: let me clear, my testView and mainView are two separate classes(subclasses of UIView) and i am asking where should i create instance of testView in mainView or in viewController?

Comment: In main view add the test view

Answer (score 1):

No you would have to add the testView as a subview of mainView, and mainView should be a part of self.view as below:

```
[self.view addSubview:mainView];
[mainView addSubview:testView];
```

Comment: my mainView is separate subclass of UIView and testView is also a separate subclass of UIView. I am asking can mainView communicate with testView or viewController has to create testView and pass it to mainView?

Comment: You need to create object of mainView in the testViewController and then add the subview of textView in the object created

Answer (score 0):

Example:
This is written in UIView Class

In .h file

```
 @Property(nonatomic,Strong) UIbutton * backButton;
```

In .m file

```
@synthesize backButton;
- (id)gettopviewwithBackbutton
  {

UIView *topView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width,40)];
topView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"retina_wood_@2X.png"]];
[self addSubview:topView];


backButton =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 5, 60, 30);
backButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:.1 green:.5 blue:1 alpha:1.0];
[backButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"back", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[topView addSubview:backButton];

return self;

}
```

This is written in UIViewController class 
TopView is the class name of above code import TopView and write this code

```
TopView *topBar =[[TopView alloc] init];
topBar.frame= CGRectMake(0, yAxis, kWidth, 40);
topBar=[topBar gettopviewwithBackbutton];
[topBar.backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:topBar];
}
```